# Principle DRY in validation?

Tags: c#, oop, dry

I use the standard DataGridView from the toolbox menu.

I do validation of each of the cells in the DataGridView by event `cellEditEnd`. It looks like this:

```
private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender,DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
     // Below I demonstrate pseudo code for brevity

     if(cell.name.value is not Number){
         print "Wrong cell value";
     }
}
```

So, in another form (WinForms) I have functionality, that imports data from an Excel file and displays it in the DataGridView.

I need to validate the Excel data before insertion in each cell. For that I can use event `CellValidation`. But I don’t want to repeat the same code, that I used in `dataGrid_CellEditEnding` method.

How can I avoid this reiteration of code?

Comment: Is there a reason not to put the validation code into a separate function and to call it both when editing and when importing from excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a static `ValidationHelper` class, with all your validation methods in it, and then calling those when required.

```
public static class ValidationHelper
{
  public static void ValidateIsNumeric(string value)
  {
    if(value is not Number){
      print "Wrong cell value";
    }
  }
}
```

Which you could then call:

```
private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender,DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
   ValidationHelper.ValidateIsNumeric(cell.name.value);
}
```

Comment: It is great, but how to know what cell I need to validate and how to validate?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll still need to know what data type each cell should be, and then write a line for each cell to pass it to the correct validator method (string, date, number etc). This just prevents you from duplicating the validation code itself.

Comment: @OlegP If you feel this answered your (original) question, then please upvote or mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look into the chain of responsability design pattern, your code will be configurable and more object oriented, will look something like this:

```
    public interface IHandler
    {
        void Handle(string value);
    }

    public abstract class CellRequestTemplate : IHandler
    {
        protected readonly IHandler _next;
        protected CellRequestTemplate(IHandler next)
        {
            _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        }

        public abstract void Handle(string value);
    }

    public sealed class FirtsRuleForCell : CellRequestTemplate
    {
        public FirtsRuleForCell(IHandler next) : base(value, next) { }
        public override void Handle(string value)
        {
            if(value is number)
            {
                _next.Handle(value);
            }
            else
            {
                //print "Wrong cell value";
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class SecondRuleForCell : CellRequestTemplate
    {
        public SecondRuleForCell(IHandler next) : base(value, next) { }
        public override void Handle(string value)
        {
            //if some validation
            //do something
            //else 
            //
            _next.Handle(value);

        }
    }

    public sealed class EndOfChain : IHandler
    {
        public void Handle(string value)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("End of Chaing, cant handle");
        }
    }

    public interface IHandleCellFactory
    {
        IHandler CreateHandler();
    }

    public sealed class Form1GridHandler : IHandleCellFactory
    {
        public IHandler CreateHandler()
        {
            return new FirtsRuleForCell(new SecondRuleForCell(new EndOfChain()));
        }
    }

    public sealed class Form2GridHandler : IHandleCellFactory
    {
        public IHandler CreateHandler()
        {
            return new SecondRuleForCell(new EndOfChain());
        }
    }


    public abstract class ClientCode
    {
        private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Below I demonstrate pseudo code for brevity
            var valueToHandle = string.Empty; //cell.name.value;
            var handler = new Form1GridHandler().CreateHandler();
            handler.Handle(valueToHandle);
            //continue with Execution code
        }
    }
```

For more info about the design patter, [look at this link as reference](http://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern).
Hope this helps, regards!